# How hard is it for a malicious hacker to make a fake PGP key with a given KeyID

Tags: key, pgp

Can anyone give me an idea of how much work would it take to create a PGP key with my name, email address and short KeyID (**8EFB369B**)?

My idea is that if it takes a lot of work, then the attacker will only bother to do it in some rare cases.

Also, the same question regarding the long KeyID **7F66ABD5 8EFB369B**. How long would it take to create a fake key with long keyID. Is fake long Key ID feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Given that KeyID is (part of the) hash of the key data, which should be random by definition, each key generation attempt could be considered as producing random KeyID. So attacker should generate ~2^32 keys for the first case, and ~2^64 for the second.

From the https://ed25519.cr.yp.to we can get that it is possible to have around ~100K keygens per sec. Neglecting SHA1 hash calculation time, short EdDSA KeyID may be duplicated in ~ 2^32/100000/60/60 ~= 10 hours.

Not much to generate key with nice short KeyID like 0xDEADBEEF :)

Another thing is that OpenPGP uses SHA1 for fingerprint calculation, so theoretically some collisions may be utilized.

Comment: Thanks a lot,
A couple more questions
1. Does attacker really need to generate keys, or can he just generate the part of the key that is being hashed.
2. I am using RSA 4096 key. Is it really possible to generate 100k key per second?

Comment: My calculation is that by hashing d == 2^32 random keys our chance to get the right hash should be 37%
===========================

((d-1)/d)^d == 37%

Comment: 1. He need to generate, as whole public key is hashed. 2. For RSA it would be much slower, calculations are based on EdDSA where secret key is random 32-byte value.